# HQL subqueries replacement

Tags: group-by, subquery, hql, having

how can I replace this subquery in HQL (as HQL doesn't support subqueries):

```
SELECT l.aUser, count(l.aUser) 
FROM LifeTable l 
WHERE l.aUser IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY l.aUser 
HAVING count(l.aUser) = 
(SELECT min(cnt) 
 FROM (SELECT count(l.aUser) cnt 
       FROM LifeTable l 
       WHERE l.aUser IS NOT NULL 
       GROUP BY l.aUser) a)
```

This query should select the aUser(s) with minimum appearences in LifeTable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `all`:

```
SELECT l.aUser, count(l.aUser) 
FROM LifeTable l 
WHERE l.aUser IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY l.aUser 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= ALL (SELECT count(*) as cnt 
                        FROM LifeTable l2 
                        WHERE l2.aUser IS NOT NULL AND
                              l2.aUser = l.aUser
                       );
```

And one slight correct.  HQL does support subqueries, just not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I'm getting an error: Column 'LIFETABLE.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. My table is bigger than the aUser column specified in the HQL. This ALL might try to select all the columns?

Comment: @WDrgn . . . I don't understand the error message.  This has no `lifetable.id` in any `select` list.  If you are trying to return additional columns, then that is a different question and should be asked as a new question.

Comment: No, sorry, it was another automatic feature from my Class. It works fine! Thanks!!!